# Как из твича вывести ссылку с видео?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Как вывести ссылку на видео в твиче? Хочу вывести из всего [каталога](https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Dota%202) ссылки на все видео.

```
url = 'https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Dota%202/videos/all'

api = ''

r = rq.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

res = soup.find_all('div', 'Layout-sc-nxg1ff-0 cQkVA-d')

for data in soup:
    print(data.content)
```

Comment: Там контент формирует `JavaScript`, используйте `Selenium`.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить все элементы, которые содержат эти классы:

```
ScCoreLink-sc-udwpw5-0 jxwNWA tw-link
```

После, вы итерируете полученный список и нужно проверить, чтобы ссылка `element.href` не содержала `"/videos"`, иначе будут дубликаты